# NX Error for Relative Imports within the Same Project

Tags: node.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nxjs

I'm getting an error when using TS aliased paths within the same project: `Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project`

I don't want this behavior. Any idea how to disable?

I tried playing with the `@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries` option, but it has almost no documentation around its options

```js
// NX doesn't like this line which uses a path to a file within the
// same NX project. It wants me to use relative pathing, which I
// don't want to use
import { fooHandler } from '@handlers/foo';
```

Comment: it's highly recommended to keep that behavior. Why would you want absolute imports?

Comment: I set up lots of aliases for my imports. Find it easier for me to grok by having:

`import thing from '@proj/controllers/thing'`

instead of:

`import thing from '../../../controllers/thing'`

Comment: I agree with @Juri and also would like to make IntelliJ Idea to make use of relative imports instead in module and alias in other modules. I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Had to look through the npm package, but found it by searching for the error text. You can disable it like this from inside of your .eslintrc.json settings:

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          // This is the part you need to add
          { "allowCircularSelfDependency": true }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. It's not a circular dependency. This just turns the error off.

Comment: @nomad in the context of nx it's a circular dependency.

Comment: This worked for me.
I tried to setup local path alias for each package in my nx project but does not work at all. 

i.e. 

`import { myUtil } from '@/shared'`

This was the only working solution for using local package aliases in nx

Answer (score 1):

For those who are coming here without this getting resolved. (nx monorepo usage)

For lint error:

`Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project - eslint rule @nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries fails`

1. Add "allowCircularSelfDependency": true.

```
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            "allowCircularSelfDependency": true, -> This may solve the lint error.
            "allow": ["@account/**"], -> // White list the lint error.
             ...
          }
```

2. Whitelist the folders: Add "allow": [@foldername]

```
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            
            "allow": ["@account/**"], -> // White list the lint error.
             ...
           }
```

That should fix it.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. It's not a circular dependency so there should be no need to do this.